# Proving minimum modulus theorem using the maximum modulus theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to prove minimum modulus theorem using the maximum modulus theorem. The problem statement is $f$ is continuous on a closed bounded region $R$ and it is analytic and not constant throughout the interior of $R$. Assuming that $f(z) \neq 0$ anywhere in $R$, I need to prove that $\mid f(z) \mid$ has a minimum value $m$ in $R$ which occurs on the boundary of $R$ but never in the interior.
I started with $$g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$$ and showed that $g(z)$ has a maximum value say $M$ that occurs on the boundary of $R$ 
  $$i.e. \qquad \mid g(z) \mid \leq M \:\:\: \forall z \in R$$but got stuck here.  I looked for the solution which further stated that: $g$ has a maximum on the boundary $R$ implies that $f$ has a minimum $m$ on the boundary of $R$. I didn't understand this implication. For if $f$ has to have a minimum on the boundary of $R$ then we must have$$\mid f(z) \mid \geq m \:\:\: \forall z \in R$$ with the equality holding atleast for one value of $z$ in $R$.
 How does $$\mid g(z) \mid \leq M \qquad  imply\qquad \mid f(z) \mid \geq m$$with the condition that even $m$ lies on the boundary of $R$ ?
How do I determine this $m$?

Comment: Take $m=\frac{1}{M}$. The minimum of $|f|$ occurs where the maximum of $1/|f|$ does.